# Accessing properties of object inside other object class

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

I have 2 object classes in my angular7 application that are filled with data - employee and company (data is received through web API from database).

Employee has fields - emp_id, name, surname and company object.
Company has - c_id, company_name, phone.
I can display employee - `emp_id`, `name` and `surname` data in table using "emp_id", "name" and "surname", but when trying to display employee company, the result displayed is "[object Object]", but I want to display `company_name`.

If data from web API is viewed from program like postman, the company object is correctly displayed inside employee object.

I have tried using these combinations to access company name - `company.company_name`, `company{company_name}`, `company(company_name)`, but none of this works.

Here are my classes in angular

```
export interface employee
{
emp_id: number;
name: string;
surname: string;
company: Company;
}
```

```
export interface company
{
c_id: number;
company_name: string;
phone: string;
}
```

Objects are filled using http.get, and saved in arrays

```
  public apartments:any [];
  public houses:any [];

  getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]>
{
  return this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://localhost:60962/api/employees');
}
 getCompanies(): Observable<Company[]>
{
  return this.http.get<Company[]>('http://localhost:60962/api/companies');
}
```

Subscribed on init

```
ngOnInit()
{
 this.getEmployees()
     .subscribe(data => this.apartments = data);

 this.getCompanies()
     .subscribe(data => this.houses = data);
}
```

Comment: please provide the code where u fill these objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, interfaces should start with capital letter:

```
export interface Employee {
  emp_id: number;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  company: Company;
}

export interface Company {
  c_id: number;
  company_name: string;
  phone: string;
}
```

Then simply declare an object like this :

```
public test: Employee = {
    emp_id: 0,
    name: "test",
    surname: "test2",
    company: {
      c_id: 12,
      company_name: "cmp name",
      phone: "+665589898"
    }
  }
```

in your html you can simply do :

```
{{test.name}}
{{test.company.phone}}
```

In your code your `interface` company starts with low 'c', while you have declared, in the object, with the 'C'

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-joap5a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html